# AWS API Gateway make single endpoint publicly available

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have successfully set up multiple API Gateways on AWS and they work perfectly with client API Keys.

Is it possible to make a specific endpoint in an API publicly available, but all other endpoints protected with the client API key required?

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS CloudFront to forward the request to API Gateway for the public endpoint and define the Client API Key in CloudFront headers forwarded to the Origin.

Note: When including API Gateway as a origin to CloudFront you need to do the following.

- Whitelist header (Except Host Header)
- Make HTTPS only
- Make TTL values 0

Comment: Apologies for the down vote. This might work, but it's complicated and would be easy to misconfigure. Much easier to use the built in option in API GW.

Comment: @Jack Kohn If you need to apply throttling and other monitoring to the public endpoint without an API Key it would be even complex. Also it will require to apply a Web Application Firewall to public endpoint since the attack surface is high, which is not directly possible without CloudFront. By the way simply down voting just thinking a solution is complex without looking at other benefits and tradeoffs is not acceptable.

Comment: Fair point, but what about the added cost of CF distribution? If you want to discuss these fine details, please add them in your answer so the OP can evaluate the solution. I will remove the downvote if you elaborate in the answer.

Comment: @Jack I just answered the question with enough detail. Have you mentioned all the points I mentioned in the previous comment won't be achievable with your answer? The added cost is a tradeoff for security, monitoring, throttling and etc. and also provides a solution to the problem stated.

Comment: Sure I can update my answer. I can't remove the downvote unless you make an edit to the answer.

Comment: Did an update you can change the vote now. I really admire your professionalism.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the `apiKeyRequired` field to `false` on whichever Methods you want to open to the public.

This is in the Method Request page in the console. Here is an example using the AWS CLI:

```
aws apigateway update-method --rest-api-id 1234123412 --resource-id a1b2c3 --http-method GET --patch-operations op="replace",path="/apiKeyRequired",value="false"
```

Please note that if you remove the requirement for an API Key, any rate limit or quota you have set up on a Usage Plan will not be applied.